# Trying to decipher a math equation notation.

Tags: functions, notation

I would like a translation "to english" of the following equation:

$$
\sigma(\alpha) : [0,1] \rightarrow \chi
$$

What is this read as? What is it trying to say?

Thank you

Comment: Is there some context? What are $\alpha$ and $\chi$. (Well, I guess $\chi$ doesn't matter much.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an equation, but a function definition. It says that $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a function from $[0, 1]$ (closed interval from zero to one) to some set $\chi$.

The notation $\sigma(\alpha)$ seems to imply that the function itself is a outcome of the function $\sigma$ at some point $\alpha$.

Comment: I asked this in the above answer, but is this as simple as [0,1] the domain of σ, and $\chi$ the range?

Comment: @Spacey The argument isn't usually written in the definition of the function like that. Reading it as it is, the name of the function is $\sigma(\alpha)$. And then $\sigma(\alpha) (x)$ is the function applied to a point $x \in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function, $\sigma$ which takes an argument $\alpha$ which can have any value between 0 and 1 (including 0 and 1).  When this function is applied, it gives a result that is inside some 'space' called $\chi$ (or 'maps' to the space $\chi$).

Unfortunately, we don't know, from your question, what $\chi$ is.  But, suppose $$\sigma (\alpha) = 1/{(1+\alpha)}$$  Then, the 'space' of $\chi$ is the interval (0,1] - in other words, the result is always less than or equal to 1, but greater than zero.  That is true because we already 'fixed' $\alpha$ to be between 0 and 1, so we can't plug in -3, for example, and get $-1/3$.

Comment: For it to be this, shouldn't the definition be $\sigma: [0, 1] \to \chi$? That is, no $\alpha$ inside.

Comment: So is [0,1] the domain of $\sigma$, and $\chi$ the range?

Comment: Yes, [0,1] is the domain, and $\chi$ is the range.  I would have left the $\alpha$ out, but I don't see any special meaning attached to having it in.

Answer (score 0):

> The function sigma of alpha maps every number of the interval zero through one, inclusive, to some element of the set (or space) chi.